# Using HDD as steam backup

Tags: system-installation, steam, hdd

I just became a linux user for a about a 4 weeks now I started with POP OS but didn't really like it. until I installed elementary OS pretty much like how it looks! and enjoying it atm, but! when I installed steam... well steam works fine but I could not use my HDD to connect to my steam library! it automatically picks the contents of my SSD! I need help integrating my HDD to my system so steam can find the drive and install games from there instead of my SSD.

Thank you guys in advance!
you new linux user
Nox The Lazyist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming a few things here:
1) You have a non-EXT4 formatted HDD (FAT, NTFS, etc). Right?
2) The drive is a SATA-connected one not a USB removable one. Right?

if so, then [THIS link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup) should tell you how to auto-mount a drive on boot, and then you'll have to go to your Steam Options and make that mount point (i.e.: /media/myHDD) the default steam library path (From Steam, click on the Steam Menu, Settings, Downloads, click on the " STEAM Library Folders" button, and set your path and default from there).

Hope this helps.
-Aldo

PS: The "GUI" option on the linked article, is super simple and GNOME Disks works perfectly with elementary :)